# How to set the constraints?

Tags: iphone

I am having one view controller in my app where i have designed a view and it has 5 levels and 10 buttons. I have also set the constraints to these. but the problem which I am facing is when I am running this app on iPhone 5s it's looking fine but when I am running the same on iPhone 6 all components scattering while on iPhone 4 the view is many components are not there on the screen. I just want to kno how to set the constraints in an effective way.

Comment: For this you have to check [autolayout for adaptive layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LayoutandAppearance.html). it will help you. For more help here, please show your screen layout then viewer get idea regarding your view scenario.

Answer (score -1):

These links may help you so please make sure to check them out:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html

Comment: Please take a look at [this question and answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). Link-only answers are not considered helpful.